# How to do -really working- OCR with a PNG input? only having azAZ09/+=

Tags: 20.04, ocr

There is a sample PNG file:

[image]

it has the following text in it (basic base64 output):

```
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
```

with the text md5sum: dafb20fbfaff84e16e9ff95a4d92fa3d

I already tried the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR OCR softwares, but wow.. they are worthless with this example, they output simply too much error in the recognized texts.

**The Question**: What am I missing? This is a good quality PNG (screenshot from a terminal). Or is there trick to do OCR with a recognition, where there is no mistake from the OCR software? Or should I increade the font size in the screenshot?

Comment: Hello. Ubuntu is an OS so I do not understand the title. What application are you using? What exact commands have you tried?

Comment: oh, sorry, updated the title!